# Hide wordpress plugin retrieve directories inside url?

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress plugin, for my plugin links I want to hide the "wp-content/plugins" part inside the url, I'm wondering how to do that?
Actually I want the url to be like wordpress pages, not showing the retrieve directories.
I'll appreciate any help

Comment: That totally depends on what kind of links/assets your plugin is using, how your plugin enqueues it. Please, [edit] the question to add details.